# Where do Neovim-questions belong? On Stack Overflow or on Vi / Vim Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, cross-posting

There is a [Vi / Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/). Both on that and on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) there is a `neovim`-tag. It has more questions on Stack Overflow than on the Vi / Vim Exchange.

With all the traction Neovim is getting, it could be cool, if all Neovim-users could rally in one place - and not be scattered across several sites/exchanges.

But I can also see the issue for all regular Vi-users (who doesn't want to use Neovim), if their lovely and clean Stack Exchange now gets filled with this next-gen version of their software.

**Question 1:** How do one decide where to ask a question regarding Neovim?
**Question 2:** I've used WordPress for a while. And with that there is a strict policy on The [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) that you can't ask questions regarding plugins. That hamstrings the WordPress Stack Exchange quite a bit, since whenever there is a probability that your question relates to something non-WordPress-core, then you'll get flagged and burnt on the stake.
... With that in mind: Where do one ask questions about Neovim plugins, such as [Nvim Telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim)?

---

### More context

The question I'm trying to ask is: 'How to setup Telescope, so it saves and closes the current file/buffer, when I open a new one'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that the Vi / Vim Stack Exchange [[neovim] tag](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neovim) already has more than a thousand questions, I don't think you need to worry about

> But I can also see the issue for all regular Vi-users (who doesn't want to use Neovim), if their lovely and clean Stack Exchange now gets filled with this next-gen version of their software.

The [telescope plugin](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-telescope) seems on-topic too. See also [What is considered to be vi?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/11357) on their Meta.

As for

> it could be cool, if all Neovim-users could rally in one place - and not be scattered across several sites/exchanges.

that could indeed be nice, but the only way to force that would be to declare it off-topic on all but one site. Honestly, I don't see that happening, and it's something which should be discussed on each site's own Meta.

As for your example question, I'm not a Neovim subject matter expert, so I'm not sure if that is enough information, but generally speaking, questions on Stack Exchange should include some details about what you already tried (or tried to search for).